# Find the number of lines that have changed between two tags in Git

Tags: git

Is there a way to tell how many lines of code have changed between tagA and tagB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git diff --stat` to do that.

```
git diff --stat tagA tagB
```

Be sure that `tagA` has occurred before `tagB`, or the results of what was removed/deleted will appear inverted.

Comment: thanks, --shortstat gives just the last line which I want.